# rpcbind causing very high load on Fedora 10 system with nfs

Tags: rpc, nfs

I've got a Fedora 10 system that's exporting some file systems via NFS.

One of the exported file systems is used very heavily on a client system when I run a search engine indexer.  The file activity is 100% read (no writes).

Whenever I run the indexer the systems load average skyrockets (up to 25 at points) and rpcbind is often using 98% of the CPU capacity.

On the client system I'm mounting the remote directory with the following options: intr,nosuid,ro,rsize=8192,udp,noatime,bg,nodev

On the server, I'm exporting the directory with the following options: ro,no_subtree_check

I have the NFS server configured for 32 threads.

If it makes any difference, the NFS server is also a NIS server.  And the client is bound to it as a NIS client.

Any suggestions on what I can do to reduce the load on the server?  Having such a high load just doesn't seem normal to me.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `nfsstat -o all` on both server and client?

Comment: Server: http://www.qtemp.net/nfsstats-server.txt


Client: http://www.qtemp.net/nfsstats-client.txt

Answer (score 0):

See what ports rpcbind are using `lsof -p $(pidof rpcbind)`

Use tcpdump to see who is talking on those ports `tcpdump -s 1600 -ni eth0 port sunrpc or port 850` you might need to look at other interfaces, including lo, in case it is locally generated traffic.

strace rpcbind to see what it is doing  `strace -s512 -o/tmp/tr -f -p $(pidof rpcbind)`